# Get rid of "text"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

> My question is about text, so I tagged it with "text".

[text](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/text)

Comment: This just makes me want to tag all my questions with "text"... Would that be so wrong?

Comment: @Spedwards: You should tag them [question].

Comment: What's wrong with [answer-wanted]?

Comment: I can see the use for plaintext... but plain text is just silly ;)

Comment: I think that's pretty ambiguous, they should clarify if they mean digital or analogue text. Or is it used as the `.text` element in a markup language or assembly (e.g. x86 assembly -[_text_ section](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/dataseg.html) )

Comment: 01010000 01100101 01110010 01101000 01100001 01110000 01110011 00100000 01110011 01101111 01101101 01100101 00100000 01110000 01100101 01101111 01110000 01101100 01100101 00100000 01100001 01110011 01101011 00100000 01110001 01110101 01100101 01110011 01110100 01101001 01101111 01101110 00100000 01110100 01101000 01101001 01110011 00100000 01110111 01100001 01111001 00111111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleanup of [text](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/text) is complete.